# eclipse not validating the struts.xml file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, struts2

I installed the eclipse in my new p.c. and import my old project of struts2 in that and after importing the project i got a warning in struts.xml file i.e. "The file cannot be validated as there was a connection problem.". I replaced my jar files and doctype so many times but still it didn't work. I also found that eclipse is not showing me any error if i do something wrong in that file even when eclipse clean my project it takes a lot of time to clean struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
 <package name="a" extends="struts-default">
 <action name="b" class="com.test">
   <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
         <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
      </action>

 </package>

</struts>
```

Please help me for this i am getting lots of difficulties...???

Comment: what is the version of struts2-core in your project?

Comment: struts2-core-2.1.8.1

Comment: i'm editing my answer. make following changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change Doctype to:

```
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "/WEB-INF/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
```

and extract "struts-2.1.dtd" file from "struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar" into dtds folder(CREATE NEW) inside WEB-INF folder.

Comment: i put struts2-core-2.3.2.0 in my jars by deleting the old one and jz did as you said but it i showing me this warning "The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "C:\WEB-INF\dtds\struts-2.3.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)" that is specified as describing the syntax of the file cannot be located."

Comment: i had edited my answer. check it. did you extract ".dtd" file from "struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar" and placed it in location /WEB-INF/dtds/

Comment: Yeah, i did it but the prob is still the same

Comment: i replaced now with the struts2.1 jar but it is still showing me that warning. Can you tell me the reason behind all this??

Comment: did you extract struts2.1.dtd file from struts-core-2.1.8.1.jar file and placed it in dtds folder? if you had done this , there should be no problem.

Comment: Yeah i did it already, but still getting this warning. Anyways thanks for you help

Comment: you can extract **struts-core-2.1.8.1.jar** and find this file **struts-default.xml**, so you can copy this head code to **struts.xml** file, hope that could help you.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when eclipse could not open the file, this happens sometimes for me when I have internet connection problems.

So make sure you have internet connection and you have not set any proxy which is not working and prevent eclipse to access the internet. You can open struts.xml and ctl+click on `http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd`

If your problem is not solved, you can do as mentioned by @AsSide, copy the struts-2.3.dtd some where in your hard and change the struts.xml as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts SYSTEM "c://struts-2.3.dtd">
```

The DOCTYPE must be changed to `SYSTEM` instead of `PUBLIC`. Change the dtd location is not a good approach :)