# Java Brains struts 2 project is not running though the code is same as the tutorial

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I'm learning struts 2 from [Java Brains](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB7BB551126EDD5E0). I've written a simple Hello world type struts 2 web application. It just shows an success page or error page. I've done everything instructed in the tutorial, but unfortunately the page is not loading. Following is the project explorer.

[image]

I've edited web.xml file like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts 2 Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

According to the tutorial, above web.xml configuration handovers the whole request response process to struts. I've configured struts.xml file like following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="action.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

I've written `action.TutorialAction` class like following.

```
package action;

public class TutorialAction {
    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("Hello From execute");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

After running the project under Tomcat 7, the url "http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action" should load success.jsp page. But it's showing 404 error.

success.jsp page is just a .jsp page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Success Page
</body>
</html>
```

I'm clueless why it's not running. I've been banging my head to solve it for a week and at last it just no hope :( . Help me please,  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have not added libraries needed in struts 2. Please change the image you provided with `libraries` node expanded.

Comment: I've included all the jars of struts 2. As they are a lot, I didn't include them in the project explorer pic. Image with lib folder extended overflows my screen, but I've included all jars of struts 2.

Comment: Banging your head won't help, you need to try something to have a clue, and the hope is useless if you don't know what do you want to get.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: what is stacktrace? @aleksandrM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/1700321.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java Brains](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB7BB551126EDD5E0) uses struts 2 Version 2.3.1.1. But the version of struts used in this project is 2.3.24. These two versions conflict. The project runs successfully using version 2.3.1.1. You can download struts 2.3.1.1 or any other older version of struts [from here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/).

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following points carefully:

1) You must add all the jar files of struts2 which is easily avaliable on "javatpoint".

2) Run it with only getTutorial instead of getTutorial.action, like "http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial"   sometimes its work.

Hope its will work for you.

Comment: what is javatpoint? I've included all the jars of struts 2. As they are a lot, I didn't include them in the project explorer pic. I tried both http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial and "http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action , neither one works.

Comment: Javatpoint is a website where you get tutorials of java, sorry for the incomplete information. You can check the link http://www.javatpoint.com/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll go through the site. Anyway, are you on struts 2 too? I saw you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252470/eclipse-not-validating-the-struts-xml-file this question on may.

Comment: Yeah i am on struts2 too, Meanwhile i am trying to solve your query asap.

Comment: @Rafaf Your code is working fine, There will be no error from my side but just be ensure that you are using the dtd version in struts.xml file according to your version of jar files added.

Comment: I think there's some configuration problem in my eclipse ... I'm using eclipse luna, jre7, tomcat 7, struts 2.3.24.

Comment: I don't think its an eclipse issue if your other projects runs fine. Try to find the problem more accurately and try to clean the project from eclipse at every updation in project.

Answer (score 0):

same problem-I downloaded struts-2.3.2 which is the oldest version in struts2 provided in the link http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/ but still comes error 404-not found with the above specified urls i.e http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial
and http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action both.

Comment: I wrote a solution of the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following points carefully:

1) You must add all the jar files of struts2 which is easily avaliable on "javatpoint".

2) Run it with only getTutorial instead of getTutorial.action, like "http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial" sometimes its work.
You can also watch Java video's from here
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWJ9QB_Ng-dgEOFd_1Ouobg